How to approach the highlighted part of the question?


The boolean expression for Z for the four input module came out to be A0A1A2+A0A2A3+A0A1A3+A1A2A3
I am attaching my work here.



I think you get your 2 input majority device, based on the 4 input device, simply by tying A0 and A1 together and calling that input 1. Similarly, tie A2 and A3 together and call that input 2.  This would effectively be a 2 input AND gate. I can't see the 3 input device being so easy, though.

If they are all to be related to each other and you need to demonstrate all three (4-in, 3-in, and 2-in) then this may be how I'd approach it. It's not optimal. But it shows a common approach that can be readily expanded or reduced, as needed. The 4-in shows that "any three" qualifies. The 3-in shows that "any two" qualifies. The 2-in shows that "both" qualifies. You can expand this idea to form a 5-in ("any three"), a 6-in ("any four"), etc. And it is instantly readable as a majority circuit.

The following is my solution (I simplified using both the rules of Boolean algebra and the Karnaugh map; resulting combinatorial network):

